# Github high severity security vulnerabilities: GHSA-7fhm-mqm4-2wp7 with a Node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, github, nodemon

After adding nodemon to devDependencies on my node.js app, i get a Security Alert on GitHub:

> moderate severity
>   Vulnerable versions: < 1.2.2
>   Patched version: 1.2.2
>   There are high severity security vulnerabilities in two of ESLints dependencies:
>   - acorn
>   - minimist
>
> The releases 1.8.3 and lower of svjsl (JSLib-npm) are vulnerable, but only if installed in a developer environment. A patch has been released (v1.8.4) which fixes these vulnerabilities.
>
> Identifiers:
>
> CVE-2020-7598
>   SNYK-JS-ACORN-559469 (doesn't have a CVE identifier)

My package.json :

```
{
      "name": "web-server",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "app.js",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node src/app.js",
        "dev": "nodemon src/app.js -e js,hbs"
      },
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "hbs": "^4.1.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "nodemon": "^2.0.2"
      }
    }
```

**I don't know exactly what should i do or should i provide more information/code about my app.**

Github repo: https://github.com/badrddinb/simple-weather-website

Comment: Is this for a private repo?

Comment: Either `nodemon` or one of it's dependencies depend on that library. Explicitly add a version of the vulnerable library that's not vulnerable to your `devDependencies`. If some library complains (or doesn't work) - raise an issue with that libraries maintainer.

Comment: I provide my Github repo on last line!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that one of your dependencies depends on an outdated version of my library. You can either add `"svjsl": "^1.8.4"` to the `"devDependencies"` object, or set every occurrence of `"svjsl"` in the "package-lock.json" file to have a version of `"^1.8.4"` and an integrity of `"sha512-U+RX1x7Tslxx68GAr1F9wBaRAjCA9cFliOSOvtWqVuVg0IRUdStsMYah/3Q8gluRomD/h3co7q4MYU62kTwzmA=="`.
It would also be a good idea to see which package depends on the outdated version and contact that package's author to tell them to update `svjsl` to a newer version.

Comment: The alert happens in all projects that have `minimist` (or `acorn`) somewhere in the dependency tree, it's not related to svjsl. I got it in multiple projects where `yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json` didn't contain the string `svjsl` at all.

Comment: @Tulir I know that the issue does not originate from my package but the alert which OP mentioned was created by myself for that package so I'm guessing they are using `svjsl`

Comment: As I said, that exact alert shows up for everyone using minimist or acorn, regardless of whether or not they use svjsl. I'm not sure why GitHub used your alert for everyone, but that just what happened.

Comment: Huh that is indeed very weird

Answer (score 1):

"minimist": {"version": "0.0.10",} in your package-lock.json is causing the ^^ issue. https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2020-7598

Remediation
Upgrade minimist to version 1.2.2 or later. For example:

"dependencies": {  "minimist": ">=1.2.2"}

or…

"devDependencies": {"minimist": ">=1.2.2"}